# Libreria PILLOW ("Edicion de fotos"), problemas al usar mas de un ajuste en la misma imagen

Tags: python, librería, pillow

He estado investigando un poco sobre la libreria PILLOW O PIL para editar imágenes con Python, el problema es que a la hora de trabajar con alguna imagen solo aplica el ultimo ajuste que le haya aplicado, me explico:

```
1  from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
2  from PIL import ImageEnhance
3
4  photo=Image.open("DSC_0096.JPG")
5
6  #ENFOQUE   
7  photo.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=20))#cambia el enfoque de la imagen
8
9  photo.filter(ImageFilter.UnsharpMask(radius=10, percent=200, threshold=5))#cambia otros parametros
10
11 photo.show()
```

En este ejemplo si añado `.show()` junto a la linea de código numero 9 solo muestra la imagen con los cambios de la linea 9 , lo cual puede llegar a tener sentido ya que estoy expresando que solo muestre la linea 9 y no debería mostrar otros cambios (como los de la linea 8), pero si uso `.show()` al final (como en la linea 11) debería poder mostrarme la foto con los dos cambios que realice ( ENFOQUE Y OTROS PARÁMETROS) y no es así, en cambio solo muestra la foto original sin ningún cambio.
Y no se si es que no se pueden aplicar mas de un ajuste en la imagen o (lo mas probable) algo estoy haciendo mal. En la documentación de la librería no menciona nada sobre que no pueda agregar mas de un cambio , pero tampoco sobre ninguna Función en especifico para guardar cambios etc... Si alguien sabe sobre la librea PILLOW, agradecería una mano, GRACIAS!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto sucede ya que como [la documentación](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) indica, `Image.show()` crea un archivo temporal. Su propósito es ver resultados tras la modificación de un archivo. Cuando se hace `show()` se está visualizando el archivo temporal generado por su modificación. Dos modificaciones producen dos archivos temporales diferentes. Una demostración:

```
a = photo.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius = 20))
b = photo.filter(ImageFilter.UnsharpMask(radius = 10,percent = 200,threshold = 5))

print(a)
print(b)
```

Salida:

```
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1100x619 at 0x108D699F160>
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1100x619 at 0x108D9981580>
```

Las modificaciones generan objetos (archivos temporales) diferentes, en espacios de memoria diferentes.

Cito esta [parte del tutorial en la documentación](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html):

> The standard version of `show()` is not very efficient, since it saves the image to a temporary file and calls a utility to display the image.

**Solución al problema:**

Se puede escribir los cambios sobre un archivo no temporal y puedes acceder a el fácilmente, ver los resultados en proceso de ejecución:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
from PIL import ImageEnhance

photo = Image.open("DSC_0096.jpg")
  
photo.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius = 20)).save("DSC_0096-mod.jpg")
photo.filter(ImageFilter.UnsharpMask(radius = 10,percent = 200,threshold = 5)).save("DSC_0096-mod.jpg")

photo_mod = Image.open("DSC_0096-mod.jpg")
photo_mod.show()
```

Se abre un archivo, se crea otro archivo, se sobrescriben la modificaciones en este archivo, se almacena en una variable y se muestra. Entonces,

```
photo = Image.open("cara-gato.jpg")
  
#Modificaciones a la imagen

photo_mod = Image.open("cara-gato-mod.jpg")
photo_mod.show()
```

Las modificaciones en la imagen que sea realizan entre esas tres lineas se mostrarán y guardarán, claro está que en otro archivo. Siempre que a la modificación se le añada el método `.save("imagen.jpg")`. El archivo debe de ser el mismo para todas las modificaciones, si se quieren ver todos los cambios en un archivo.

Si se deseara moficiar el archivo que se abrió en primera instancia directamente, se debe de hacer el `.save()` con el nombre del archivo que se hizo el `Image.open()`. Trabajar con dos archivos distintos asegura una modificación segura, sin dañar el archivo original.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Si perfecto muchas gracias!!, Seguro entendí mal esa parte de la documentación